Library for parsing GML3.2 geometries (including 3D) in Java
I'm looking for a Java library that can reliably parse GML 3.2 geometries, including 3D geometries, directly from XML. I've tried using GeoTools, but it seems to only handle some basic geometry types (e.g., simple points), and even then, 3D support is limited to specific representations.
import org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration;
import org.geotools.xsd.Parser;

    private Geometry parseGML(String gmlString) throws Exception {
        String fixed = convertUrnToEpsg(gmlString);
        GMLConfiguration gmlConfig = new GMLConfiguration();
        Parser parser = new Parser(gmlConfig);
        var parsed = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(fixed.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        if (parsed instanceof Geometry[] geometries) {
            for (Geometry geometry : geometries) {
                System.out.println(geometry);
            }
        } else if (parsed instanceof Geometry geometry) {
            System.out.println(geometry);
            return geometry;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Type: " + parsed.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        return null;
    }


For example, this works fine with GeoTools:
String gmlElevatedPoint = """
    <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
        <gml:pos>52.1 -0.1 100</gml:pos>
    </gml:Point>
    """;
Geometry geometry = parseGML(gmlElevatedPoint);


But this fails:
String gmlCurve = """
    <gml:Curve gml:id="exampleCurve" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
        <gml:segments>
            <gml:GeodesicString>
                <gml:posList>
                    57.0833 -40.0 52.85
                    -41.7833 48.4667 -41.3333
                    44.0333 -40.0 42.6
                    -37.0 40.7333 -37.1833
                    41.4 -30.05 43.5167
                    -21.1333 56.6667 -21.1333
                    57.0833 -40.0
                </gml:posList>
            </gml:GeodesicString>
        </gml:segments>
    </gml:Curve>
    """;
Geometry geometry = parseGML(gmlCurve);


Are there any other libraries that can parse more complex GML 3.2 geometries, especially 3D curves and surfaces? Or is there a specific way to configure GeoTools to support these cases? Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Is there any library available for handling AIXM geometries?

as discussed at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/480604/geotools-gml-3-2-parsing-to-geometry-does-geotools-suport-all-gml3-2-types - there seems to be a need to add some code to handle curves in GeoTools GML parser.
